# Error styling Select2 for Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I'm working with Bootstrap 4, and for the `<select>` elements i want to use [Select2](https://select2.org).

The problem is that it does not have a official Bootstrap 4 template, so i was looking and i found [this](http://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.0.html) project, which is awesome.

But i having one issue with `is-invalid` class.

When i use it, the `<select>` borders change to red when the page loads and then return to its normal state

I try to make a simple class to use with the same Bootstrap color like

```
.invalid-select2 {
  border-color: #dc3545;
}

.invalid-select2:focus {
  border-color: #dc3545;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.25);
}
```

But the result is the same;

You can see the problem in
[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ao9bu15h/)

Someone has idea how can i deal with it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: When using select2 the original select element gets "hidden", that's why you get the impression of being originally red bordered and then back to normal when select2 renders.

With a little bit of JS you can check if your original select has the class "is-invalid" and apply that to the select2 element.

Comment: I'm curious, why are you applying is-invalid by default?

Comment: @funkysoul ty so much! i'll try :D

Comment: @JonathanChaplin I'm applying to test; i'm using asp.net mvc with ModelState to determine if that class must be there :D

Comment: @funkysoul i'm trying that and thats working, i only had a hover problem , do you have some idea to detect the opening of that span to add is-invalid class again? ty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flikcering is because you're adding the class the the select box's class attribute so the style is applied immediately. Afterwards, select2 classes are applied which hides the select box (causing the flicker).

One way around this is to simply apply the class when the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#combo').select2
  ({
    theme: 'bootstrap'
  });

  $("#combo + span").addClass("is-invalid");

});
```

EDIT: To fix the focus problem you're experiencing you need to over-ride a couple of classes.

```
.is-invalid .select2-selection,
.needs-validation ~ span > .select2-dropdown{
  border-color:red !important;
}
```

`.is-invalid .select2-selection` selects the top part of the dropdown, and the second class (`.needs-validation ~ span > .select2-dropdown`) selects the actual dropdown list. Note that I've added `.needs-validation` to the top level div once the form is validated you can simply toggle that to `was-validated`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/ao9bu15h/6/)

Comment: Thanks for response! I was looking it, but i see it without borders in the jsfiddle, it must look like this https://jsfiddle.net/ao9bu15h/3/

Comment: I see. give me a second.

Comment: I got almost solved with *funkysoul* comment, i fighting with the border when the select is opened :p

Comment: try this in your document.ready :   $("#combo + span").addClass("is-invalid");

Comment: Its working, i'm doing something similar, `$('select.is-invalid.select2-hidden-accessible').each(function(){
    $(this).next('span').addClass('is-invalid');});` but the problem is adding the is-invalid:focus when the select is opened, thanks!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170300/discussion-between-jonathan-chaplin-and-juan-salvador-portugal).

Comment: Thanks! you are amazing!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use some CSS to style a red boarder

```
.is-invalid + .select2-container--bootstrap .select2-selection--single {
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
}
```

Comment: With Bootstrap 4 : `.is-invalid + .select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--single {
    border: 2px solid #dc3545;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to add !important to css property?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the solution :'( Thanks for the response!